# Normalize response through multiple joins in a single query with solr

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

It's possible to perform a query to the following solr collection

```
{
    "id":1,
    "book_name":"Solr book",
    "category":[1,2,3],
    "author":[1]
},
{
    "id":1,
    "book_name":"Rocky",
    "category":[3],
    "author":[2]
},
{
    "category_id": 1,
    "category_name":"Technology"
},
{
    "category_id": 2,
    "category_name":"Apache Lucene"
},
{
    "category_id": 3,
    "category_name":"Sport"
},
{
    "author_id": "1",
    "author_name" "Chuck Norris"
},
{
    "author_id": "1",
    "author_name" "John Rambo"
}
```

which will return something like:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "book_name": "Solr book",
    "categories": ["Technology", "Apache Lucene"],
    "Authors": ["Chuck Norris"]
}
```

searching by book_name AND/OR category_name AND/OR author name in a typical Searchbox input? or an alternative response, which I will return something similar?

Otherwise which is the preferred workaround/best practice to achieve it?

...we would like to perform a single query through out the Frontend web App **without** using the Backend web App to structure the response, because that data is already in solr.

Comment: do you have this type data on development environment or its on the production environment...?

Comment: it's in development environment. But I already found the solution here http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Full_Import_Example

Comment: Could you share what exactly been done or helped you to resolve this...?

Answer (score 0):

The way I've settled up the collection was wrong, I did it this way:

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
            driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/circulo_lectores"
            user=""
            password="" /> 
  <document>
        <entity name="book" query="SELECT * FROM book">

            <field column="id" name="id"/>
            <field column="book" name="book" />

            <entity name="book_author" query="SELECT * FROM book_author WHERE book_id= ${book.id}">         
                <field column="author_id" name="author_id" />
                <entity name="author" query="select * FROM author WHERE id = ${book_author.author_id}">
                    <field column="author_name" name="author_name" />
                </entity>                   
            </entity>   

            <entity name="book_category" query="SELECT * FROM book_category WHERE book_id= ${book.id}">         
                <field column="category_id" name="category_id" />
                <entity name="category" query="select * FROM category WHERE id = ${book_category.category_id}">
                    <field column="category_name" name="category_name" />
                </entity>                   
            </entity>               

        </entity>   
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

This [reference](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Full_Import_Example) gave me the clue. Hope it helps someon else